# Compile a piece of code in debug mode with Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt

I am showing you my problem.
I'm creating an application in Qt Creator for a university project.
As you can see in the code below, I inserted two 'cout' inside a method just because they were useful to me to check that the program worked, this means that they have no real function.
After viewing it, the professor delegated me to do it in debug mode with #IFDEF so that that portion of the code containing the 'cout' is visible only to the programmer and not to a hypothetical client.
I hope I have explained my problem fairly well, I thank anyone who can help me.
Consider that in this type of thing I am quite novice.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use preprocessor macro. The correct one for qt creator is `QT_DEBUG`. Your code should look like this:

```
void BankAccount::addTransaction(Transaction* t){
    if(t->getType()==0 && actualAccountBalance < t->getTransactionValue()) {

#ifdef QT_DEBUG
        cout<<"Unable to add transaction: insufficient balance to make the requested withdrawal!"<<endl;
#endif

        ; // empty command, because of empty if
   }

   else if(find(transactions.begin(),transactions.end(),t) != transactions.end()) {

#ifdef QT_DEBUG
        cout<<"This transaction has already been added!"<<endl;
#endif

        ; // empty command, because of empty if

    }

    else{
        transactions.push_back(t);
        assignID(t);
        actualAccountBalance = calculateAccountBalance();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the complete answer.
I rewrote the code exactly as you said but gives me the following error:
"else without a previous if".
The error appears both for 'elseif' and for 'else' at the bottom

Comment: Try again with the brackets `{}` after if and else if `{}`

Comment: I removed the two `;` after `#endif` and now it gives me no error.
The message written inside the two `cout`is still printed in application output.
How can I verify that what I have to do has been satisfied?

Comment: You should learn how preprocessor macros works. You have to use the brackets, because you have more than one line in your if-else statement. Then you should verify, if you compile a debug or a release build. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I solved, thank you very much for your help and patience ;)